# How do I search a string for any characters within an array in classic ASP?

Tags: arrays, search, asp-classic

I currently have the ASP following code, where if a particular non-Latin character "д" appears in my search string, I get a desired response as below.

```
myQuery = request("myQuery")

If InStr(1, myQuery, "д", 1) > 0 then
    Response.write "Query from languages ......  detected." 
 Else 
    Response.write "Continue searching English/Latin archive."
End if
```

But how do I replace my single character with an array of characters:

```
myArray = Array("ß","ü","ş","ğ", "ä", "д", "ф")
```

In other words, how do I check to see if any of the characters in myArray appears in myQuery?

Answer (score 2):

Depends on the need, you either can loop through the array

```
For Each x In myArray 
    If InStr(1, myQuery, x, 1) > 0 then
        Response.write x + " was detected." 
    Else 
        Response.write "Continue searching English/Latin archive."
    End if
Next
```

or use regular expressions to test in one shot

```
Dim myRegExp, FoundMatch
Set myRegExp = New RegExp
myRegExp.Pattern = "[ßüşğäдф]"
FoundMatch = myRegExp.Test(myQuery)

If FoundMatch then
    Response.write "Characters detected." 
Else 
    Response.write "Continue searching English/Latin archive."
End if
```

Comment: Thank you so much for that. I used your reg. expression code and it works a treat. You've saved me hours of stress ))

Comment: Glad it helped. Marked as answered.